# Flat option for CJUIDateTimePicker Yii

Tags: datetimepicker, yii-extensions

I'm trying to show calendar as inline for CJUIDateTimePicker widget,

```
<?php widget('CJuiDateTimePicker',array('id'=>'recalldate','name'=>'Time','attribute'=>'eventDate',
          'mode'=>'datetime',
          'language'=> Yii::app()->request->cookies['language'] == 'en' ? 'en-GB' : Yii::app()->request->cookies['language'],
          'options'=>array('changeMonth'=>'true', 
                             'changeYear'=>'true',   
                         'minDate'=>'0',
                             'yearRange' => '+0:+4',        
                         'showAnim'=>'fold',
                         'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                             'value'=>date('yy-mm-dd'),
                             'theme'=>'redmond',                 
                     ),
           'htmlOptions'=> array('disabled'=>'disabled') 
             // jquery plugin options
            ));?>
```

Please can anyone help me to make as inline calendar as like option (flat) in CJUIDatepicker !!!

Answer (score 0):

flat is a public property in `CJuiDatePicker` 
can be accessed like

`'flat' => true`

```
<?php

$this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker', array('id' => 'recalldate', 'name' => 'Time', 'attribute' => 'eventDate',
    'mode' => 'datetime',
    'language' => Yii::app()->request->cookies['language'] == 'en' ? 'en-GB' : Yii::app()->request->cookies['language'],
    'options' => array('changeMonth' => 'true',
        'changeYear' => 'true',
        'minDate' => '0',
        'yearRange' => '+0:+4',
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
        'value' => date('yy-mm-dd'),
        'theme' => 'redmond',
    ),
    'flat' => true,
    'htmlOptions' => array('disabled' => 'disabled')
        // jquery plugin options
));
?>
```